# IE8 CSS issue with floats and % width containers

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, width, css-float

I've run into what appears to be a CSS issue with IE8.

```
  <html>
    <body>
      <div style="width:180px;">
        <div style="text-align:center; border:1px solid black;">
          <div style="width: 40%; background-color:red;">
            <div style="width:180px; float:left;">
              <div>Text</div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

This gives me the following results:

[image]

The doctype is set to strict. The reason the text divs are in a div that can have a width of anywhere from 0-100% is to give that variable width div the proper height.

What do I need to do in order to achieve the first effect in IE8?

Some key elements to this are that the height cannot be fixed because the text could overflow the width of the box. The height of both the containing box and the "fill" needs to be able to vary based on content.

Comment: I have just checked your code in Firefox and IE8 and it appears to be displayed the same way. Also when I change the width % it is aplied both to Firefox and IE8. Are you using IE8 or some IE Tester?

Comment: You have a 180px width INSIDE of another 180px width but also have a 40% width inside that SAME 180px width element - makes no sense to me.

Comment: It might be more beneficial for you to ask what you're trying to achieve rather than asking why your current code isn't working.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know what the poster wants, just removal of the innner 180px width, or modification of that to some smaller amount to give the inner some "padding" of the 40% width, centered...simple removal does give a centered text with red background but matches neither of the examples posted.

Comment: Mixing all caps with all lowercase is a curious coding style.

Comment: And the mixing of DIV and div does NOT meet strict depending on the document type.

Comment: Sorry guys, that DIV/div thing came from copy pasting some output from IE8's dev tools. It was originally written in all lower case. I was in a hurry when I put this up this morning and didn't take the time to correct it. As for what I want - the image for IE9, Chrome, etc shows what we are trying to achieve. Think of it as a progress bar with text inside. The % width is adjusted to reflect % complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solves the issue of a variable height:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="bar"></div>
   <div class="text">Text<br/>MoreText</div>    
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}

.text {
    position:relative;
}

.bar {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MdRmV/)**

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
    <div class="bar">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: none;
}

.text {
    line-height: 20px;  /* make this match the height of .bar */
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.bar {
    height: 20px;  /* make this match the line-height of .text */
    width: 40%;
    position: relative;
    top:0; left:0;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

**Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/WE9xv/2/**

Comment: @RyanElkins: However, I correctly answered your question as originally presented.

Comment: @RyanElkins: You have a real conundrum here.  The progress bar `div` is a sibling of the text `div` so the two heights will be independent of each other unless you specify it or use JS.  On the other hand, what about the inconsistent look of the progress bar when you allow the text to wrap?

Comment: @RyanElkins:  I exactly answered your original question before you altered it thereby making it unanswerable.  The fair thing to do would be to accept my original answer to your original question.

Comment: I upvoted your answer since it is useful and it's not your fault I didn't provide as much information as I should have. The edit feature is there so I can edit the question rather than start a whole new one because I left something out the first time. It's not unanswerable, either. I've since figured it out and will update this question with the correct answer. Thank you for your help. Actually your answer was very close and just needed some tweaks.

Comment: @RyanElkins, Ok, thank-you.  However, the most correct thing to do would be to post your final solution as another answer and accept it instead of putting the answer within your original question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just did. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse in modern browsers you can just use the html 5 tag 'progress'.

Source:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp